# What process is it when the polytropic index $n$ is equal to $- \infty$?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

From 
$$Pv^n = \mathrm{constant}$$ 
When $n = - \infty$ 
What kind of process is it.... 
Eg... When $n= \infty$, 
It is constant volume....

Therefore when $n =- \infty$... 
What is constant?

Comment: Is this a serious question or is it an "I was just wondering" question?

Comment: Hi Chimaobi, welcome to the Physics SE. Please use the MathJax syntax for your math expressions to make them better readable.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
P v^{-\infty} &= K
\\
\frac{P}{v^\infty} &= K
\\
\frac{v^\infty}{P} &= \frac{1}{K}
\\
v^\infty\frac{1}{P} &= \underbrace{\frac{1}{K}}_{K'}
\end{align}
Variations in $v$ get scaled by an exponent of $\infty$ and are therefore infinitely more important in determining whether the result is $K'$ than variations in $1/P$ are. The process is still constant volume.